# Android google map gray grid

Tags: android, dictionary

I created an android application using Google map I generated a key signed for distribution in the market with this key I generated an MD5 to generate the Android Maps API key android:

```
apiKey = "0kHWNnZhgMPg19T3YMmSXOgUakRz-TkkiLk7gWg"
```

then generated the apk and upload it to market but when I donwload the application and use the map I get a gray grid and the map don't shows me the map what I can be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using Eclipse and you used the Export command and pointed it at the same key as what you used to generate the Maps key it should work.  The problem is that somewhere you either used a different signing key, or did not export and sign your app with that key, or you uploaded an apk that was built using your debug key.  Those are the reasons to get a grey background.